# Conditional matching with Grep using PCRE regex not matching conditional part as expected

Tags: git, grep, pcre, githooks

I'm trying to implement a *Git hook* that will check that the commit message complies with a commit template. To do this I thought of using regular expressions (which seems obvious). The rules are the following:

1. The title must contain one or more tags in relation to the nature of the commit. Each of this tags are surrounded by "[ ]" and there are an specific set of them.
2. The title must be under 72 characters.
3. The title must be at least a word (not a single character).
4. The body of the message, if included, must be separated of the title by an empty line (this would mean two line jumps).
5. The body of the message, if included, must be more than a single character.

Having these said rules I came up with the following regex: `(?=(?:\[(?:feat|fix|style)\])+\s\w{2,}).{8,72}(?(?=.*\n{2})\n{2}\w{2,})`. The regex works fine when I test it in [RegExr](https://regexr.com/) but it does not work as expected when I test it with **grep** (I test it out just in my terminal with a sample file).

This would be the command line instruction with grep: `$ grep -P "(?=(?:\[(?:feat|fix|style)\])+\s\w{2,}).{8,72}(?(?=.*\n{2})\n{2}\w{2,})" holas.txt`. Where the file "holas.txt" just contains the following: *[feat] Hola\n\nHola*. Running this command returns just one match with the first line (*[feat] Hola*) and not with the text in the body of the message which should be matched by the **conditional part of the regex**. If I just delete the line in the body it also matches the first line, but this shouldn't be like that, it shouldn't match (I have tested it out with the mentioned online tool).

I have also tried using **pcregrep** but the result is the same.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Grep reads the input line by line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution! If you use the **-z** flag, grep interprets the file as just one line (it replaces **\n** with **null** char). This means that the regex would be applied to that whole big line and not to each and every line by itself.

So simple... I should have read the documentation better.